# Installing 2 year old application

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, typescript-typings

I started a project 2 years ago that I now can't seem to install into other directories.

I used to follow these steps to install my angular frontend

npm install gulp
npm install typings
npm install
typings install
gulp build

I never had to do them again and it correctly installed a typings folder from which the gulp file found all it packages, it worked and I didn't mind how.

I am now trying to install it again and it does not fill the typings folder correctly, there only appears a index.d.ts file.

I found here https://github.com/typings/typings/tree/abea10b5787e1a18634d5f37bb2fa56550c32fd1
that it should've been around version 1.0.4.
So I try to install with:

```
npm install typings@1.0.4
```

But this still does not install any typing directory.
Any direction I should look into further would be apreciated.

Comment: Anthing more I can do to improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting all my files in the package.json to the specified version an not just compatible with changed the error to [Syntax error parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475188/angular-frontend-syntax-error), I was able to fix that with removing a translate application.

Answer (score 1):

If you look have a package.json file for the 2 year old project (which you should) then you should find the version numbers of each dependency in there.

Comment: It contains gulp 3.9.1, is that right that this didn't change? But it contains nothing for typings

Comment: Yeah, gulp version may not have changed since then. So it's perfectly valid. If you have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings you may be able to find why your process isn't working as this is the package on the npm site

Comment: or try the git repo for the package https://github.com/typings/typings/

Comment: you may then find that you can work out how to use this newer version with out any issues.

Comment: I found what should have been the original version. It didn't work so I'm now at a total loss as to what is causing my problem.

Comment: where did you find this build process?

Comment: it seems you may have to update and learn how to use it with the newer versions

Comment: The original 'framework' I built this on didn't update either and suffers from the same problem that you can't download and build it anymore.

Comment: So in the gulpfile.js? Shouldn't the typings file get installed in typings install?