# Angular frontend syntax error

Tags: angularjs, typescript

When I start my angular frontend I get the following syntax error

> choose.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at
>   position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.fromJson (vendor.js:14110)
>       at Object.getObject (vendor.js:4234)
>       at Object.get (vendor.js:4347)
>       at Object.get (vendor.js:47560)
>       at runTranslate (vendor.js:47789)
>       at Object.invoke (vendor.js:17454)
>       at vendor.js:17262
>       at forEach (vendor.js:13111)
>       at createInjector (vendor.js:17262)

The vendor.js is automatically created and when I look up the error it is really specific to what people wrote and not something auto generated.
Any idea in which direction I need to look:

At 14110 is the following segment:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name angular.fromJson
 * @module ng
 * @kind function
 *
 * @description
 * Deserializes a JSON string.
 *
 * @param {string} json JSON string to deserialize.
 * @returns {Object|Array|string|number} Deserialized JSON string.
 */
function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json)
      ? JSON.parse(json)
      : json;
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(json); instead of JSON.parse(json)

Comment: All code in vendor.js is generated after I build my angular application with gulp so I don't know how to change this.

Comment: have a look at my answer, is there anything in your build script (some gulp plugin) that could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not really been able to confirm it and it is not a real solution but the line

> at runTranslate (vendor.js:47789)

led me to believe there was a fault in my translate app. Because I did not need it I removed it from my application and it indeed solved my problems.
This of course is not a true fix but it was enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not in vendor.js nor in way the vendor.js is compiled. It says `Undexpected token I in JSON at position 1`. That means your application is trying to parse JSON object (with above mentioned function `fromJson` and fails as it stumbles upon invalid JSON string.
Put breakpoint on the function and re-run the app to see which JSON exactly crashes. Hopefully you'll figure out then what you did wrong.

Comment: You can use Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug for example. If you click on the right side next to your console error report (something like vendor.js:x) it will take you right to the function fromJson. Just place breakpoint there and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the compiler or something else inserts **;** at the end of the return statement.

Thus transforming your into something like this which is invalid javascript.

```js
function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json);  // added ; here
      ? JSON.parse(json) // no longer valid javascript
      : json;
}
```

Make sure the code is not transformed this way, or write the ternary expression on a single line.

Comment: I don't think my gulp buildscript does that and the code I copies is the live version in the chrome developper tool so I'm pretty sure there is no ; there

Comment: and the version you run is not minified in any way?